# Proving Formula Equivalence using Equivalence Laws

Tags: logic

I'm taking Discrete Math for CS, and we went over Equivalence Laws the other day.

Prove equivalence of f and g for:

$f(x,y) = \lnot ((x \land \lnot y) \lor (x \land y))$

*Test Case 1*:

$f(F,F) = \lnot ((F \land \lnot F) \lor (F \land F))$

```
   = not (F or F) 
   = not (F)
   = T
   = not (F) <----- I get lost here.
   = g(F,F)
```

I'm not understanding how this proves anything. My problem is how do I know what g(x,y) is (the formula on the right of the equal sign). I'm not understanding why when I reach the value T, f(F,F) = g(F,F) is proven?

We're supposed to test equivalence using every possible parameter: (F,F),(F,T),(T,F),(T,T).

So the main question is: When I finally reach T, what does that mean?

Comment: You haven't told us what $g$ is.

Comment: @RickDecker: He says that $g$ is the formula on the right of the equal sign $$g(x,y)=\lnot((x\land\lnot y)\lor(x\land y))$$
but that is what $f$ is, so I am not sure what is being asked.

Comment: @RickDecker: after writing my answer, my guess is that $g(x,y)=\lnot x$

Comment: @PatrickJean: You state that $f(x,y)=\lnot((x\land\lnot y)\lor(x\land y))$. Did you omit that $g(x,y)=\lnot x$?

Comment: @robjohn. That was my guess, too. +1 since we're in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\lnot((x\land\lnot y)\lor(x\land y))=\lnot x$. Here is the truth table showing this:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x&y&f(x,y)&\lnot x\\
\hline F&F&T&T\\
\hline F&T&T&T\\
\hline T&F&F&F\\
\hline T&T&F&F\\
\end{array}
$$
if that is the question.